# Searching for String in array list (Java)

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I created a method which searches for a string in an array list, however I the problem is, if I search for a book it has to be the exactly how it was inputted into the array list.

e.g if I type in "Harry Potter" as a book title and search for it, I have to put in "Harry Potter", I can't put "harry potter" or "HARRY POTTER"as it won't recognize it, i know there is something called ignore case but can't get it to work, or may have had it in the wrong place.

My code:

```
public void searchBook() {

    System.out.println("\n"+"Enter the title of the book you would like to search for: ");
    String search = input.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < newBook.size(); i++) {

        // IF statement to check that any book in the array list equals what
        // the user has typed in
        if ( newBook.get(i).getTitle().equals(search)  ) {

            System.out.println(("Book ID: " + newBook.get(i).getBookID() + "  Title: " + newBook.get(i).getTitle()
                    + "    Author: " + newBook.get(i).getAuthor() + "  Genre: " + newBook.get(i).getGenre()
                    + "   Date registered: " + newBook.get(i).getDateReg() + "   Loan Status: "
                    + newBook.get(i).getLoan() + "    Number of times loaned: " + newBook.get(i).getNumOfLoans()));

        } else {

            System.out.println("No match was found");
        }

    } // end of for

}// end of method
```

Comment: Please try if ( newBook.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())  ). This way is more correct

Comment: Rather than calling `newBook.get(i)` a ton of times, call it once and store it in a local variable.

Comment: You should go with contains method and lowercase conversion as Tuna said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if (newBook.get(i).getTitle().equals(search)
```

to

```
if (newBook.get(i).getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(search)
```

The `equalsIgnoreCase` performs a String comparison ignoring case.

Answer (score 1):

use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()`

Read for documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

from javadoc,

> Compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations.
>   Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same
>   length and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal
>   ignoring case.

Answer (score 0):

For searching `contains` method is more correct

```
if (newBook.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: Explain how it is more correct than equalsignorecase method, and how you consider contains over equalsignorecase?

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase(String)` already does its own case conversion operations internally and is *much* easier to read.

Comment: Dear friends. we all know what equalsIgnoreCase() is. But he is inputting a text. The text may be "rry" then he couldnt find any answer for him.

Comment: Well, I support @Tuna Karakasoglu for this case. This kind of implementation will cover more cases and return more legit result. I dont know why people down-voted this answer.

Comment: Well, read question again, but sorry cannot vote up again locked. i am with this answer.